# How to make roles based middleware to access the api's with proper rights in nodejs and mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to make websites which have the roles permission
It will be as

```
SuperAdmin - will approve admins and will have all right which admin have

Admin - will approve articles and will have all the rights which loggedin user have

Loggedin User - can post articles and will have all the rights which guest user have.

Guest(Non Loggedin User) - can see articles.
```

I have an idea to make schema which have `role key`, I make all api's but don't know how to give permission so that particular `apis` was access by one who has right for that.

Can please someone help me in make this auth middleware?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, first of all, you should have a user's role in your `req` object. I assume you did it. Then you can specify aliases for your roles in Database. For instance

```
SuperAdmin - superadmin

Admin - admin

Loggedin User - user

Guest(Non Loggedin User) - you do not need to have a role for a guest, you just can check whether user authenticated or not
```

The example middleware will look like

```
// Authentication middleware
const isAuthenticated = (roles) => (req, res, next) => {
  // `roles` argument is an array of roles
  // We check whether user authenticated or not.
  // If user authenticated, `req.user` will be object otherwise it will be `undefined` 
  if(req.user) { // `req.user` is a user object from Database
    // Checking whether `req.user` has a corresponded role
    if (roles.indexOf(req.user.role) !== -1) next(); // `req.user.role` is string and it may be "admin", "superadmin", or "user"
    else res.status(403).send({message: "unauthorized"}); 
  } else {
    res.status(401).send({message: "unauthorized"});
  }
};
```

And you can use this middleware on router

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

// Example routes

// This route is for guests
router.get('/articles', (req, res) => {
  res.send({'article': 'lorem ipsum'})
});

// This route is for authenticated user
router.get('/forOnlyAuthUser', isAuthenticated(['user']) (req, res) => {
  res.send({user: req.user})
});

// This route is for admin
router.get('/forOnlyAdmin', isAuthenticated(['admin']) (req, res) => {
  res.send({user: req.user})
});

// This route is for superadmin
router.get('/forOnlySuperadmin', isAuthenticated(['superadmin']) (req, res) => {
  res.send({user: req.user})
});

// This route is for all authenticated users
router.get('/forOnlyAllAuthUsers', isAuthenticated(['user', 'admin', 'superadmin']) (req, res) => {
  res.send({user: req.user})
});
```

You can customize `isAuthenticated` function as you want

Comment: Thank you so much, I saw many ways but this is the best for me.